# Can I control (manipulate) the address bar using MVC .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to invoke this URL:

```
www.example.com/home/brand1
```

but have the resulting URL be:

```
www.example.com/brand1
```

I want to do this with multiple brands. I know I can have an action in the home controller for each brand which redirects to a brand controller but I don't want a controller for each brand. I imagine I can do this with routing but just don't know how.

Comment: Have a look at routing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: [Great pluralsight resource on routing](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m2-controllers&mode=live&clip=1&course=mvc4-building)

Answer (score 2):

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                                               
        "{brandName}",                           
        new { controller = "Home", action = "YourBrandAction", brandName = "" }  
); // inside RegisterRoutes method 



//Your Controller
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult YourBrandAction(String brandName)
   {
     //your controller logic...
     return View(yourBrandModel);
   }
}
```

You must be very careful with the above route configuration. Some URLs, e.g. *www.example.com/login* will not direct you to the login page but treat 'login' as a brand name.